# beforeRouteLeave with <a href> creates strange interaction

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element-ui

I an currently developing an app that involves user to change some of the data on the page, to make sure the user would save before moving on to other pages, I used beforeRouteLeave + element-ui to create a message as an reminder. The code kanda looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="this.$router.push(path)">To homePage</div>
    <div :href="path">To homePage</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    console.log('the start')
    if (this.saveRemind) {
      console.log('in if')
      this.$confirm('Are you sure you want to continue？', 'Notice', {
        distinguishCancelAndClose: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        type: 'warning',
        duration: 0
      }).then(() => {
        next()
        console.log('in then')
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log('in catch')
        return
      })
      console.log('end of confirm')
    } else {
      console.log('in else')
      next()
    }
    console.log('in the end')
    return
  }
</script>
```

Now the problem is that the if <div @click> is clicked, everything works fine, the confirmation message box would appear and stay on page until i decide to click 'yes' or 'no', but on my first click on , it would go streight through the message box, the box will appear and disappear instantly, and in console I can observe that 'in then' or 'in catch' are not printed(other console.log are printed). On my second click on , everything works fine again. Thus given any  on the page, I have to click it twice to make it work properly and this is obviously not user friendly enough. Any idea why this is happening to my app?

Comment: Can you replicate it on this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-butterfly-ukelr?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue? On that codesandbox, it works as I expect it to be.

Comment: I tried window.confirm in my code and it works perfectly, the element ui msg box seems to be bugged  imo. thanks for the suggestion, ill just go for window.confirm to save me some hassle.